# Signing an Unsigned dll changes dll behavior

Tags: c#, dll, strongname

I'm not sure what to ask exactly because i'm not sure exactly whats the problem. I have a project that needs all its assembly files to be signed and i have a 3rd party assembly that's unsigned. I'm using the ilasm and ildasm like case 2 in this article [Signing an Unsigned Assembly](http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/). After that i can use the dll but it's behavivior is different from before ( a property in one of the classes can't be used). Just to clarify if i use the dll in a side project without signing them they work fine

What could have gone wrong and what can i do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found what the problem is, I had an old version of this dll in the GAC,once i deleted it everything works fine